# Cannot sort gridview in des order, neither can sort on another column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have this grid view, it has 2 problems.

1. if I sort it by clicking on a column, and then I click again, its not sorted in des order.
2. If once I sort with a `col A` and then click on any other column its not sorted again?

   ```
     <asp:GridView ID="grdReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustCode"
   ShowFooter="True" EmptyDataText="No record found" PageSize="50"
   CssClass="mGrid" onrowdatabound="grdReport_RowDataBound"
   AllowSorting="True" onsorting="grdReport_Sorting">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"/>
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblCustCodes" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustCode") %>' CssClass="grdCustName"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="Customer">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>' runat="server" ID="hplNavigate">
      </asp:HyperLink>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="QTY" HeaderText="Booked Qty" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
           SortExpression="QTY">
           <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
       </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Volume" HeaderText="Booked Amt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
           SortExpression="Volume">
           <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
       </asp:BoundField>
       </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstBill" HeaderText="First Bill" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left"
           SortExpression="FirstBill">
           <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
       </asp:BoundField>
   </Columns>
   <FooterStyle BackColor="Aqua" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="BlueViolet"/>
   ```

The code behind for sorting is

```
        switch (e.SortExpression)
        {
            case "Customer":
                if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<string>("CustomerName")
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<string>("CustomerName") descending
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();   
                }                    
                break;

            case "QTY":
                if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<int>("Qty")
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<int>("Qty") descending
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();   
                }                    
                break;

            case "Volume":
                if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<float>("Volume")
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<float>("Volume") descending
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();
                }
                break;

         case "FirstBill":
                if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<DateTime>("FirstBill")
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby table.Field<DateTime>("FirstBill") descending
                                 select table;
                    var dv = result.AsDataView();
                    grdReport.DataSource = dv;
                    grdReport.DataBind();
                }
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
```

And the row data bound event is

```
 protected void grdReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        # region try
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && Ob.DatasetMain.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                if ((Ob.FromDate != null || Ob.FromDate != "") && (Ob.UptoDate != null || Ob.UptoDate != ""))
                {

                    ((HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("hplNavigate")).NavigateUrl =
                       String.Format("~//Reports/BookingByCustomerReport.aspx?BC={0},{1},{2},{3}", Ob.DatasetMain.Tables[0].Rows[Ob.Counter][0], Ob.FromDate, Ob.UptoDate, radReportFrom.Checked);


                    Ob.Counter++;
                }
                if (hdnFromCustomer.Value == "true")
                {
                    ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked = true;
                }
            }

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                if (Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Total";
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Text = Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows[Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1][2].ToString();
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows[Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1][3].ToString();
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Text = Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows[Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1][4].ToString();
                    e.Row.Cells[6].Text = Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows[Ob.DatasetOther.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1][5].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        # endregion
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

To again list out problem

1. I cannot sort by des when I click again
2. If I sort out by say, customer name, and then click on `qty` or any other I get `Specified cast is not valid.` Means, I cannot sort out by clicking any other column once I sorted by any particular column.

Can anyone help me figure out problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to allow your gridview to sort on your gridview property

```
 AllowSorting="true"
```

moreover you have to store your sort in cache (viewstate or session).use a session variable to store the latest Sort Expression and when you sort the grid next time compare the sort expression of the grid with the Session variable which stores last sort expression. If the columns are equal then check the direction of the previous sort and sort in the opposite direction.

Example:

```
DataTable sourceTable = GridAttendence.DataSource as DataTable;
DataView view = new DataView(sourceTable);
string[] sortData = Session["sortExpression"].ToString().Trim().Split(' ');
if (e.SortExpression == sortData[0])
{
    if (sortData[1] == "ASC")
    {
        view.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";
        this.ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";
    }
    else
    {
        view.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
        this.ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
    }
}
else
{
    view.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
    this.ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
}
```

Comment: you might wanna change `Session["sortExpression"]` to `ViewState["sortExpression"]`

Answer (score 1):

In grid the when AutoGenerateColumns = “false”, the e.SortDirection will always be ascending. The workaround is you need to store the last sortorder for column (or you store last sort order of each column) in ViewState

```
    public const string ASCENDING = "Ascending";
    public const string DESCENDING = "Descending";
```

Define property , to retain the SortOrder

```
    public string GridSortOrder
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(ViewState["SortOrderKey"]) == string.Empty ? ASCENDING : "Descending"; }
        set { ViewState["SortOrderKey"] = value; }
    }
```

In the grdReport_Sorting event, made the

```
     if (GridSortOrder == ASCENDING)
        {
            var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                         orderby table.Field<string>("CustomerName")
                         select table;
            var dv = result.AsDataView();
            grdReport.DataSource = dv;
            grdReport.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {
            var result = from table in Ob.DataTableOther.AsEnumerable()
                         orderby table.Field<string>("CustomerName") descending
                         select table;
            var dv = result.AsDataView();
            grdReport.DataSource = dv;
            grdReport.DataBind();   
        }

         /*
         * logic for remaining columns 
         */

        //Change the sortOrder
        ChangeSortOrder(GridSortOrder);
```

Change Sort Order Method

```
    public void ChangeSortOrder(string currentOrder)
    {
        GridSortOrder = currentOrder == ASCENDING ? DESCENDING : ASCENDING;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";
static private DataView dvReports;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // i am assuming that you are binding the gridview on page_load
        // you can use the same on a button click event too
        dvReports = new DataView(Ob.DataTableOther);
        BindGridView();
    }
}

protected void grdReport_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        dvProducts.Sort = sortExpression + DESCENDING;
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        dvProducts.Sort = sortExpression + ASCENDING;
    }
    BindGridView();
}

private void BindGridView()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dvReports
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
}
```

I am writing this for you because if you are binding with a `DataTable` there is no need to make it `IEnumerable` and do custom sort. That's not necessary and also lots more lines of code.

Framework is your friend. Happy Coding.